# How can I optimize this Query with Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have an array of book ids and I need to iterate each and save the number of comments for each in a Hash (@book_comments) that will have the book_id as the key and the number of comments for that book as a value. Book has many comments, comment belong to books.

```
@book_ids.map {|id| @book_comments[id] = Book.find(id).comments.size}
```

This will hit the DB with these two queries for the amount of ids I have on my array.

```
SELECT `books`.* FROM `books` WHERE `books`.`id` = ? LIMIT 1
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `comments` WHERE `comments`.`book_id` = ?
```

Surely there's a better way. 
If you know, please teach me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should get your hash:

```
@book_comments = Comment.where(book_id: @book_ids).group(:book_id).count
```

Comment: Does it performs only one query?

Comment: Yes it does, this is the best answer.

Comment: Really nice, @seph :) +1

Comment: Thanks @NicNilov !

Answer (score 3):

Use this code:

```
comment_counts_by_book = Book.select('books.id, count(comments.id) as comments_count').
    joins('left outer join comments on comments.book_id = books.id').
    group('books.id').inject({}) { |h, book| h[book.id] = book.comments_count; h }

comment_counts_by_book
# => {1=>2, 2=>5, ...}
```

It does a single database query returning `Book` objects with only `:id` and `:comments_count` attributes filled out. The result is then transformed using `inject` to a hash with book ids as keys and comments counts as values.

Comment: See @seph's answer for the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Rails 4 you can do the following as well:

```
Comment.eager_load(:book).group(:book).count
```

It'll generate something like this:

```
=> #{1=>2, 2=>4, 3=>9}
```

Comment: This is a terse piece of ruby but it works in two separate queries. First query extracts all `book.id`s from comments and passes them to the second query as a parameter. Note that the array of ids gets returned to the client and is not the same as a subquery. The approach will work for a small example but will not on a large dataset.

Comment: You're only showing the first query. Take a look at the next one, starting with `SELECT "books".* FROM "books" WHERE "books"."id" IN (1, 2, 3, ...`

Comment: I just noticed I forgot to use the `eager_load` method, thanks for the notice :)

Comment: I think you want: `Comment.where(book_id: @book_ids).group(:book_id).count`. Only generates 1 query.

Comment: @seph, I don't have rails project in my front right now, but now with `eager_load` I think it'll all generated with 1 query (**btw, a giant query**).

Comment: The question wants to restrict it to `@book_ids`?

Comment: The only difference with `eager_load` is the first query became `DISTINCT`. It still works in two steps, passing fetched ids through the app.

Comment: Well, not really. `eager_load` perfoms a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, but as I said, I'm just trying.. I don't have any rails project in my front right now.

Comment: @NicNilov, can you test it?

Comment: This is what I'm doing, running on Rails 4.2.6. Yes it does perform left outer join. It actually comes quite close with the first query but runs the second one anyway.

Comment: Sure. The first one: `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "comments"."id") AS comment_id, book_id AS book_id FROM "comments" LEFT OUTER JOIN "books" ON "books"."id" = "comments"."book_id" GROUP BY "comments"."book_id"`

Comment: The second one: `SELECT "books".* FROM "books" WHERE "books"."id" IN (1,2,3,... really long list of ids`.

Comment: Sooo strange, it seems like `includes` method. `Eager_load` should perfoms it all together.. Did you really test it?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you? I'm not sure if I understood the question correctly. Let me know.

```
Book.find(@book_ids).map(&:comments).size
```

#### Update

Is this closer to what you want?

```
@book_ids.map do |id|
  {
    id => Book.find(id).map(&:comments).size
  }
end
```

#### Try this, too

```
{}.tap do |hash|
  @book_ids.each do |book_id|
    hash[book_id] = Book.find(book_id).map(&:comments).size
  end
end
```

Comment: This returns me the same size of the array  book_ids. What I'm trying to get here is a hash book_comments containing as a key the id of the book and the value would be the number of comments that book has. And that hash will have the info for all the book ids I have in the book_ids array. I'll edit to say that info in the question. Thanks

Comment: @Breno -- Just updated the answer. Let me know how that works for ya.

Comment: @DylanRichards The point is to optimize the query. Your examples still do `N` requests to the database.

Answer (score 0):

You should use includes to eager load the comments then iterate over that query.

```
books = Book.where(id: @book_ids).includes(:comments)

books.each do |book|
  @book_comments[book.id] = book.comments.length
end
```